# Get GeoJSON from a VectorGrid.Protobuf layer on click event

Tags: leaflet, geojson, vector-grid

I am trying to get the GeoJSON of a VectorGrid layer on a click event.

Something like this:

```
...
var vectorTile = new L.vectorGrid.protobuf(url, options).addTo(map)

vectorTile.on('click', e => {
   let layerJson = e.layer.toGeoJson() //toGeoJson is not a function of layer
});
```

My goal is to be able to store the GeoJSON of the clicked layer in a db, so I can draw it later on another page.

I was not able to find a lot information about this in the internet.

I found a similar question/request, but no solution:
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/176

Is this doable? Any suggestion on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, it's not. According to https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/177 they only have a `.toGeoJSON(x, y, z)` method to convert an exact tile into a GeoJSON.
They also say, that `vector-tile-js` is able to convert an exact feature to geosjon, but not `Leaflet.VectorGrid` .

Comment: I think, the solution for your problem actually depends on a layer source. Where does your features come from on a map? If you browse a layer from your tile server, maybe you could also get a clicked feature's geometry from some API by request. But if a user draws this feature on a map, then the best way is to keep your layer as GeoJSON, so you could easily extract a needed feature by click.